# VisualSVN Server repo folder not accessible after being shared

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am running VisualSVN Server on a server which I connect to via TortoiseSVN. On the server, all my repos are contained within the folder `C:\svn`.

Suddenly, after sharing this folder, I cannot gain remote access to my repositories via TortoiseSVN. All I get is a "500 internal server error" after my username and password are rejected.

Sharing the folder has clearly altered the permissions. I followed [this guide on the VisualSVN website](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00022/) but to not avail. How can I regain access?

Comment: What's logged to VisualSVN Server log? https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a quick, hacky solution to this. It involved the following:

- Make a copy of `C:\svn`, called something like `C:\svn - Copy`
- Delete the original `C:\svn` folder
- Rename `C:\svn` - Copy to `C:\svn`

This properly restored my permissions and gave me access via TortoiseSVN again.